# How to rename an asset on file upload Craft 4

Tags: assets, events, craft4, filesystem, volumes

I am looking to update some custom module code which updates the file name on upload. In Craft 3 I had this working by listening to the `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE` on an Asset. It would detect the ID of the volume it was uploaded to and then change the file name to a random string which then resave the entry to the folder it was saved in.

Since Craft 4 and the changes with filesystems I am no longer able to get back to the volume ID to compare, testing the folder ID does not help as the assets uses a temp folder until the element (User or Entry) has saved.

The `volumeId` returns `null` within Craft 4, the output shows `-_volumeId: null`, sometimes it does have a value against it under certain circumstances.

What is the best way to do this in Craft 4?

I have included the code I was using.

```
const RENAME_ASSET_VOLUME_FOLDER_IDS = [2,3];

public static function renameAsset($event)
{
    $asset = $event->sender;

    $isNew = $event->isNew;

    // Only update the filename for new assets
    if ($isNew) {
        // Volume ID
        $volumeId = $asset->volumeId;

        // Test if asset volume ID is in volume folder array
        if (in_array($folderId, self::RENAME_ASSET_VOLUME_FOLDER_IDS)) {
            // Get folder
            $folder = $asset->getFolder();

            // File extension
            $extension = $asset->getExtension();

            // Generate random string
            $randomString = ToolboxHelper::randomString();

            // New file name
            $newfileName = $randomString . '.' . $extension;

            // Update file title
            $asset->title = $randomString;

            // Save asset
            Craft::$app->assets->moveAsset($asset, $folder, $newfileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but where to put this code?? i should create a module and paste this code into ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `EVENT_AFTER_PROPAGATE` instead of `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE` as the `EVENT_AFTER_PROPAGATE` event fires after the full save process has completed for an element. See the [Events page in the Extending Craft docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/events.html#event-code-generator) for more details.

To check if a new element is being saved, you should use this inside the event handler:

```php
if ($event->sender->firstSave) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this event, it still returns null for the volumeId and the folderId is still the temporary ID. Currently I can't find a way to relate the asset to a volume or the correct destination folder to be able to check if this asset is one which would be amended.

Comment: Is this for when saving an asset on its own, or as part of an entry?

Comment: My usecase would be an asset field in an element (Entry or User) as well as directly within the asset section of the CP.

Comment: FWIW, `$asset->volumeId` still works on my end – tested both in a `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE` and `EVENT_AFTER_PROPAGATE` event handler, on the latest Craft 4 release. Something is likely wrong somewhere...

Comment: Interesting. Will have to look into this more then

Comment: I have had a play around, disabled all plugins and commented all other custom event code besides the renaming of the assets. The same issue is happening where. I've even added a new asset field to test that and the same output happens, no Volume ID and the folder details are `folderId: 16`, `uploaderId: 1300`, `folderPath: "user_1300/"` This is always the same, I presume this is the temp folder.